# Truncating and rounding integer numbers

Tags: architecture, numbers, rounding, truncate

There's a question about if it there's a meaning in truncating and rounding **integer** numbers, should we do those operations ot it's worthless?

The obvious answer should be: Yes, if you have 10 bits available and you need 12 then you MUST truncate the 2 least significant ones.

But I'm not sure if that's a 100% correct opinion.

(This question is architecture oriented)